# $.get() - pass data to outside function through callback? (close please)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple question: Can you init a function in the callback of a `$.get()`?

For example, this doesn't alert "get":

```
function outside() {
    alert('get');
}
$.get('foo.txt', function(data) {
    outside();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d69vz/3/

However, using `$.ajax` alerts "ajax" as expected:

```
function outside() {
    alert('ajax');
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.txt',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        outside();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8zqZ/

I realize that `$.get()` is just `$.ajax()` stripped, but how am I supposed to know whether I can use an outside function in a callback?

**Edit: Close this, it is a personal mistake.**

The file I was calling had a `header('Content-type: application/xml');`, so the "intelligent" data-type set by jQuery was "xml" when it should have been set to "html." My code works with `$.get()` when you use:

```
function outside() {
    alert('get');
}
$.get('foo.txt', function(data) {
    outside();
},
"html"
);
```

Comment: As long as the function is in scope, you can always call another function in the callback, and your top example is exactly like the example in the [**manual**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), which you of course read before asking this.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I've added jsfiddle's, check the first one, it doesn't alert anything.

Comment: your code seems work http://jsfiddle.net/JSr7V/

Comment: hmmm wait I didn't add the /echo/html/

Comment: weird my code is exactly the same as that example, yet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Your jsfiddle fails because the request for 'foo.txt' returns an error. Here is an example of a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pXSmj/

```
var speak = function() { alert('hi'); }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('../img/logo.png', function(data) {
        speak();
    });
});​
```

Here is an update to your jsfiddle with `outside` being called to the failure of the request for foo.txt: http://jsfiddle.net/d69vz/1/

Comment: you're right, I just realized that, I'm going to go and try to figure why it isn't working in my code. Man I've been fiddling with this stuff for hours!!